# Chisel: val differs from expression after assignment

Tags: scala, chisel

I am writing an interrupt controller in Chisel.

The following function determines the highest priority pending interrupt. Each interrupt source is represented by a `IRQStatusReg` and the combined register file is a Chisel `Vec`. To determine the interrupt with the highest priority, a recursive divide and conquer strategy is used. In hardware, this should be synthesized as a tree of multiplexers. The returned tuple contains the register and its ID.

```
def select_highest_prio_irq(vec: Vec[IRQStatusReg], start: Int, len: Int) : (IRQStatusReg, UInt) = {
    if(len == 1){
        return (vec(start), UInt(width=0))
    }
   else{
       val left_len = len / 2
       val right_len = len - left_len
       val (left, l0) = select_highest_prio_irq(vec, start, left_len)
       val (right, r0) = select_highest_prio_irq(vec, start+ left_len, right_len)
       val select_left = left.irq_pending && !left.irq_masked && left.irq_prio > right.irq_prio
       printf("val: %x\n", select_left)
       printf("expr: %x\n", left.irq_pending && !left.irq_masked && left.irq_prio > right.irq_prio)
       (Mux(select_left, left, right), 
        Cat(!select_left, Mux(select_left, l0, r0)))  
    }
 } 

val (highest_prio_reg, irq_nr) = select_highest_prio_irq(irq_status_regfile, 0, intSources)
```

However, this function fails to determine the correct result when using certain register configurations and 4 interrupt sources. The reason lies in the assignment to select_left: The value of the expression on the right hand side differs from the value select_left has after the assignment (see line 3/4):

```
val:0
expr: 0
val:0
expr: 1
val: 1
expr: 1
```

How is that possible? How can a val have a different value than an expression after an assignment?

For reference, here is the definition of the IRQStatusReg Vec:

```
class IRQStatusReg(priorityLevels: Int) extends Bundle {
  val irq_prio = UInt(width = log2Up(priorityLevels))
  val irq_masked = Bool()
  val irq_pending = Bool()
  override def cloneType: this.type =
      new IRQStatusReg(priorityLevels).asInstanceOf[this.type]
}
 val irq_status_regfile = Reg(init = Vec(intSources, new IRQStatusReg(priorityLevels)))
```

Comment: I am unfamiliar with chisel; Are you running `select_highest_prio_irq` more than once? if so, are these calls `select_blah` going to some db?

Comment: No, there is no interface to a DB and select_highest_prio_irq is called exactly once.